# calculating total values from a JSON data in jsreport using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsreport

I am new to jsreport. I have the following data and trying to calculate total salaries,

```
{
    "company": [{
            "Remy": {
        "age": 32,
        "employer": "emp1",
        "salary": 20000
    },
    "Piet": {
        "age": 35,
        "employer": "emp2",
        "salary": 50000
    },
        "Thando": {
        "age": 32,
        "employer": "emp3",
        "salary": 20000
    },
        "Greg": {
        "age": 33,
        "employer": "emp4",
        "salary": 70000
    }
    }]
    
}
```

I tried using the following code but I keep getting an error that company.forEach is not a function

```
function total(company) {
    var sum = 0
    company.forEach(function (i) {
        sum += i.salary
    })
    return sum
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Report "Issue" render failed.

Error when evaluating engine handlebars for template anonymous
(because) "total" helper call failed
(because) company.forEach is not a function

(sandbox.js line 14:13)

  12 | function total(company) {
  13 |     var sum = 0
> 14 |     company.forEach(function (i) {
     |             ^
  15 |         sum += i.salary
  16 |     })
  17 |     return sum
```

Comment: @derpirscher, i have edited the question to include the error message i am getting

Comment: What is passed as `company` parameter to your `total` function? Obviously it's not the `company` array from the data shown above ...

Comment: Can you show as how/where you called the total() function and what argument you passed?
Error: ".forEach is not a function" means the passed value (in this case company) was not an array.

Comment: note that your `company` is actually an array with only one object inside of it which then has the employee's names as the keys to the employee objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good time to use reduce:

```js
const data = {
    "company": [{
        "Remy": {
            "age": 32,
            "employer": "emp1",
            "salary": 20000
        },
        "Piet": {
            "age": 35,
            "employer": "emp2",
            "salary": 50000
        },
        "Thando": {
            "age": 32,
            "employer": "emp3",
            "salary": 20000
        },
        "Greg": {
            "age": 33,
            "employer": "emp4",
            "salary": 70000
        }
    }]    
}

const salaries = Object.values(data.company[0]).reduce((total, emp) => {
    total = emp.salary + total;
    return total;
}, 0)

console.log(salaries)
```

Have a look at the array reduce method for details, but whenever you hear 'calculating' on a list of items reduce isn't a bad option to have a look at to try to solve the issue